# How to convert Quandl json to Python dictionary?

Tags: python, json, api, quandl

```
{
    "dataset": {
        "id": 2288715,
        "dataset_code": "ORB",
        "database_code": "OPEC",
        "name": "OPEC Crude Oil Price",
        "description": "Reference Price for the OPEC Crude Oil Basket.  Currently includes: Saharan Blend (Algeria), Girassol (Angola), Oriente (Ecuador), Iran Heavy (Islamic Republic of Iran), Basra Light (Iraq), Kuwait Export (Kuwait), Es Sider (Libya), Bonny Light (Nigeria), Qatar Marine (Qatar), Arab Light (Saudi Arabia), Murban (UAE) and Merey (Venezuela).",
        "refreshed_at": "2019-12-02T12:25:30.433Z",
        "newest_available_date": "2019-11-29",
        "oldest_available_date": "2003-01-02",
        "column_names": [
            "Date",
            "Value"
        ],
        "frequency": "daily",
        "type": "Time Series",
        "premium": false,
        "limit": null,
        "transform": null,
        "column_index": null,
        "start_date": "2019-11-26",
        "end_date": "2019-11-26",
        "data": [
            [
                "2019-11-26",
                63.92
            ]
        ],
        "collapse": null,
        "order": null,
        "database_id": 381
    }
}
```

I tried this code below but it does not work and does not display details on the HTML. How do I convert the json to python for the data to be display on the html page?

```
        #convert from JSON string to Python Dictionary
        oilData = json.loads(response.text)
        #TO retrieve the latest data from Meta Data
        lastRefreshedDate = oilData["data"]
        #To retrieve latest stock price
        latestOilPrices = oilData["Date"][lastRefreshedDate]
        closingPrice = latestOilPrices["Value"]
return render_template('oil_price.html',tCode=Code,sPrice=closingPrice,dTime=lastRefreshedDate)
```

EDIT: error faced

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\shirl\Downloads\OBKD_Part2_Group (1)\oBKD part 2\app.py", line 138, in result
    latestOilPrices = oilData["data"][lastRefreshedDate]
KeyError: 'data'
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Dec/2019 12:30:48] "POST /result HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Comment: maybe you should send it to template - `render_template('oil_price.html', closingPrice)`

Comment: did you get error message ? Did you use `print()` to check what you get in varialbes? As form me you don't have problem with JSON but with template.

Comment: @furas i did send it to the template but got a key error 'data'. I did not use print() to check i

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: and don't change text/code in question. Add it at the end of question with prefix `EDIT:`

Comment: `key: data` may means that you search `["data"]` in wrong place in JSON data. If you have this error with `variable["data"]` then you should check what you have in variable - print(variable)` or in template `{% variable %}`

Comment: I see error - you don't have `oilData["data"]` in your JSON file but `oilData["dataset"]["data"]`

Comment: BTW use `print(variable)` to see values in variable. You can also use `print( type(variable) )` to check if it is list or dictionary. If it is dictionary then you can see `print( variable.keys() )` to see keys. And then you can see `print( variable['some_key'] )`,  `print( type(variable['some_key']) )`,  `print( variable['some_key'].keys() )`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix the data so it's readable by python:

```
import re
jdata = re.sub(r'(?:false)','False',jdata) 
jdata = re.sub(r'(?:null)','None',jdata) 
pydict = eval(jdata)
```